# Unable Redirecting to a New Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I want to redirect to a new page on a button click. Suppose that I have a button in my **Default.aspx** as:

```
<asp:Button ID="signup_but" runat="server" Text="SignUp" onClick="Register"></asp:Button>
```

and I want to redirect to a new page when I click this Button my Register Method is in **Default.aspx.cs** as:

```
protected void Register(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Registration.aspx");
}
```

---

The Problem is that when i click this button to redirect to a new page as **Registration.aspx** it does not redirect my to the page and shows the following URL:

```
    http://localhost:18832/My%20First%20WebSite/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMy+First+WebSite%2fRegistration.aspx
```

Comment: this is because of the authentication.. registration page needs authentication.

Comment: if i use it for another button just to test, it behaves same

Comment: you need to remove the authorization from the directory where you have registration page.

Comment: try to use Response.Redirect("/Registration.aspx"); without the ~ (that's how I usually do it). Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an authorization model on your site, and the path `~/Registration.aspx` isn't allowed in your config file.

You should add this code to your web.config file:

```
<location path="Registration.aspx"> //path here is path to your register.aspx page e.g. it could be ~/publicpages/register.aspx
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/> // this will allow access to everyone to register.aspx
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

More information about allowing and denying the site paths can be found on:

- [allow Element for authorization (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config)

Comment: where should i place this tag please can you tell me I am facing problems